# Jump to beginning of output of last command

Tags: 16.04, command-line, gnome-terminal

This is a question I've had for around a decade now and I've never found an answer.  To make it specific though, I'll ask in the context of my current environment.

On Ubuntu 16.04, using the gnome terminal, **is there a way to jump to the beginning of the output of the last command you ran or to the line containing the last command itself?**  Ideally I would like to assign this action to a convenient hotkey.

Obvious use case: anytime you compile something and get more than a screen of errors.

This is so simple, but I haven't come across a way yet.  Some pathetic alternatives:

- Redirect output to file, then open the file in an editor.  Problems: adds developer time/overhead/annoyance; probably lose bash formatting when opening in file, making output harder to read; overall generally negating time saved over just scrolling up.
- Pipe to `less`.  Problems: same as above, plus it doesn't seem to start at the top of the output or let me scroll properly.
- Pipe to `grep -i error`. Problems: likely won't show the relevant lines of the error message (need successive lines), any grep solution is not robust in general, and again adds overhead.
- Search upwards in your console for `username@computername`? Problems: don't know if it's possible in gnome terminal (other terminals [can do it](https://askubuntu.com/a/469788/792580)), not robust (though pretty good), maybe slow to type.

Have people really been scrolling up to find their error messages all these years?  I feel I must be missing something.

Edit: best alternatives so far:

- Run `reset` before the command, then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> after executing the command to jump to the top of the terminal, as given in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/378665/296541).
- Pick a different terminal that supports searching, as per [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/469788/792580).

Comment: Related (on [unix.se]): [Scroll to the last command on Terminal? (like OS X Terminal marks)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287541/scroll-to-the-last-command-on-terminal-like-os-x-terminal-marks)

Comment: Wow, the workaround mentioned there is actually the best I've seen so far.  I will use that for now.  In the meantime, I wonder if any more direct solutions have come up in the last couple years.

Comment: "Search upwards [...] don't know if it's possible in gnome terminal", "Pick a different terminal that supports searching" – Hey, gnome-terminal has a toplevel menu called Search.

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer before: If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** at the left of this text right now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the number, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](/questions/ask)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

Erm, you can do that with the standard `gnome-terminal:`

[image: Search animation]

The only thing I did was to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to start the search and the standard is `Backwards` already...

Just ensure that you have enough scrolling lines available to scroll back to by changing the scrollback limit:
<kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Profile Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>Scrolling</kbd>
8192 just takes a few KB of RAM so enter whatever number that suits ***you*** there!

[image: gnome-terminal settings]

**Also:** for short hops up and down, don't forget about <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PgDn</kbd> *even while you're compiling.* (No, it will not pause compiling: just add lines out of your view...)

Answer (score 0):

VTE based terminals, such as e.g. GNOME Terminal, GNOME Console, Xfce4 Terminal, Terminator, Tilix, Guake and more, support this feature since the GNOME 46 (VTE 0.76) release in March 2024.

The hotkey is hardcoded for the time being, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>.

Under the hood, VTE uses the quasi-standard OSC 133 shell integration escape sequences to see where the prompts are, like several other terminals already do.